# Tridion and Appfabric caching

Tags: 2011

I am not sure if it is really a tridion question.
I have installed Appfarbric server and want to configure tridion IIS web site to use appfabric caching. I don't want to use in-memory IIS caching.
Has anybody used Appfabric with tridion?

Comment: I think you're right this really doesn't sound all that Tridion relested and your question is very low quality. You don't say what your architecture is. Please help the community to help you by putting a bit more detail into your question. In it's current form it is likely to be closed.

Comment: Definitely it is not Tridion related. Use the App Fabric for the published site from Tridion and out of Tridion configure the App Fabric like you do for any Non-Tridion site

Comment: I agree with the above, it sounds like your question has little to no relation to SDL Tridion, unless you actually would like to install AppFabric on the SDL Tridion CME website, but you don't give enough information at current. I suggest you edit your question and make it more clear (wouldn't harm to remove the spelling mistakes either), or in case it isn't really Tridion related at all, then we can migrate it to a more suitable place like ServerFault.

Comment: I would regularly agree to it being off-topic, but as Eric mentions you may have trouble with the ADF - which is Tridion specific

Comment: The questioner does state that he wants to use appfabric with the Tridion IIS web site. So it's on-topic, if perhaps quickly answered.

Answer (score 5):

AppFabric cache serialize objects to make sure they are available in a distributed environment, it shouldn't be an issue with Tridion as long as what you want to serialize is `Serializable`. For instance if you are using Ambient Data Framework and want to put claims in cache you will have problems since the `ClaimStore` object is not serializable and some data included in your claims could not be `Serializable`.